# Is there an online temporary code bin for C#? (JS Bin, jsFiddle clones)?

Tags: c#, jsfiddle

Is there a website that offers simple temporary code bin's for C#?

Syntax highlighting is a plus. I've found nice ones for JavaScript: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: What's a 'code bin'? Can it run code, or is it simply for publishing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're looking for http://pastebin.com/ or http://www.ideone.com/.

Answer (score 12):

Just found out `.NET Fiddle` that supports C#/VB.NET for console application. It's also allows sharing and collaboration. Another one is `CodeRun Studio`.
Just one more finding: `C# Pad` - an interactive web based C# REPL.

- [.NET Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/) - mentioned above
- [CodeRun Studio](http://coderun.com/) - ASP.NET using C#
- [C# Pad](http://csharppad.com/) - an interactive web based C# REPL

Comment: and just found out .NET Fiddle supports (some) NuGet dependencies!

Answer (score 7):

Yet another: http://rextester.com/runcode

Answer (score 6):

Just found this from a dup question. Here's another  http://compilify.net/

Comment: It seems to spend most of its time broken in some way; I suspect the project may have been abandoned.

Answer (score 4):

http://ideone.com/ also supports C#. You can paste code and run it, too. Syntax highlight can also be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Another two interesting sites:

http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php & https://compilr.com/ (now you have to pay for using it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://executify.com/ for simple code examples.